# Toshiba laptop with Windows 98 shows corrupted characters while booting, then the system goes entirely blind

Tags: video, windows-98, troubleshooting, toshiba

I have a Toshiba laptop and I am not sure what is going on with it.  Thinking that maybe the computer was corrupted 20 plus years ago.  Trying to fix it up.

When the laptop boots, I can see this on the screen:

[image: Text-mode screenshot of the system booting; the screen displays C→\▲SET MSINPUT↔C→\MSINPUT on one line, and the caret is displayed below]

About 20 to 30 seconds later, the command disappears and I get a blank screen. If I blindly play around with <kbd>Backspace</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and other keys, I can actually get it to start (the Windows 98 startup chime can be heard) and it acts like I am on the desktop, but I cannot see anything.  Also notice the funny looking characters: where the colon should be, there is an arrow... It is like this on other screens as well, with double exclamation points replacing characters and so forth.  I know the screen works because it displays the initial toshiba message and I was able to see a BIOS menu (once).  Have not been able to get there again.

I am able to press and hold <kbd>F8</kbd> to go into Safe Mode successfully, but not sure what to do in Safe Mode.  I tried refreshing various displays, but have not had any luck.  I also tried installing the hard drive in another computer and booting it there: I did not get the full desktop (it asked me to install drivers for new hardware first), but the funny fonts were gone and it showed standard characters.

Wondering if the operating system is corrupted.  Do I need to reinstall the OS?  Can I bypass the command?  If anyone has experienced this weirdness before, I would appreciate advice on what to do to actually be able to use the laptop normally.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's not "asking for" anything.  That is just an echo of a legitimate command from autoexec.bat (though you have some weird font/character code issues).  MSINPUT is something to do with 'Intellitype' support for certain keyboards. [See here](https://www.astonisher.com/archives/bugnet/database/readme/readme_mskeyboard.htm).

Comment: FWIW, the previous post was from an unregistered account, so maybe 'Shawn  Hardgrove' cannot edit the original.  Mods, is there some way to attach the old question to the new registered account?

Comment: @another-dave There is, but mods aren't allowed to do it any more after the Incident. Instead, use the [contact us](/contact) form to contact Stack Exchange employees.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up all. I contacted CS to see if they can combine my original question with this one. I was having trouble editing the original question, so I decided to register and repost.

Comment: One of the simpler ways to troubleshoot this is to take out the harddisk, connect it to some PC, and have a look at the startup files and see if they are good. As for possible reasons, in can be everything, from CPU fault, to motherboard fault, to harddisk fault, to corrupted hard disk, to fan fault or power supply fault.

Comment: Off the screenshot alone, it looks like the ASCII range [0x3a, 0x3e] is corrupted into [0x1a, 0x1e] (bit 5 forced off) in screen memory. Can you run a thorough memory test (a la memtest86 or something similar)? Maybe it can reveal something more.

Comment: Per the other post, it'll boot into safe mode.  Safe mode is there in order to diagnose/repair problems.  I'd start by looking at video config.

Comment: @another-dave Safe mode is there to diagnose/repair *software* problems. This has the hallmarks of a hardware problem. Specifically with the video RAM, if not the whole video adapter, if not the memory bus itself.

Comment: Nevertheless, since safe mode reportedly works, it may be instructive to reconfigure the video driver.  If you can get the OS running in 'normal' mode by using base VGA, you've learned something.

Comment: I tried placing the hard drive in a known working computer, and that computer did not start up. Once again it displayed the MSINPUT. However it did start recognizing new stuff, like the pci and it wanted me to insert win 98 se cd rom to install drivers. I dont currently have a cd rom, but I am planning to get one soon. I am wondering if I just replace or update the drivers with what is on the cd rom if that would clear some things up. In safe mode I did not see anything related to intellitype. Strangely, the funny fonts are gone now and it is showing standard characters. Thanks for the advice!

Comment: No, don’t bother. You’d just install superfluous drivers that will be useless on the original machine. Like I said, run [a thorough memory test](https://memtest.org/) on the original machine first, then see if you can somehow replace or repair the video adapter.

Comment: *"Strangely, the funny fonts are gone now and it is showing standard characters."* - I believe the characters are in ROM and therefore what you see depends on the machine it's running on.

Comment: By the way, if you want to enter BIOS setup, you probably want this: <https://web.archive.org/web/20220531044152/https://content.us.dynabook.com/content/support/downloads/tsetup.exe>. Run it from a pure DOS prompt. Should work with most Satellite, Portege and Tecra models.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a full diagnosis, but one hypothesis can be formulated just from the screenshot.

It shows a setting from AUTOEXEC.BAT printed to the screen during booting.  What the setting does is immaterial; the interesting thing is that the line that would ordinarily look like `C:\>SET MSINPUT=C:\MSINPUT`, here is displayed as `C→\▲SET MSINPUT↔C→\MSINPUT`.  This corruption of video memory is not quite random: mapping those characters to [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Code_page_437&oldid=1138255107) code points, we see that `:` (0x3a) is corrupted into `→` (0x1a), `>` (0x3e) into `▲` (0x1e) and `=` (0x3d) into `↔` (0x1d).  In other words, bit 5 of the character code is cleared.  This sort of thing is suggestive of a hardware fault, for example the fifth data line of the memory bus being broken.  This is somewhat corroborated by the fact that the symptoms disappear when the hard drive is booted in another computer.

Given that the system otherwise seemingly runs normally, and all symptoms as described seem limited to visual problems, one should hope the problem is contained entirely within the video adapter.  But there are other possibilities: it may be a problem with the mainboard itself, with the memory bus, or perhaps with the RAM modules.  It would take dismantling the laptop and thoroughly inspecting it to precisely locate, confirm and repair the issue.  Before you attempt that, running a thorough memory test like [memtest86+](https://memtest.org/) may reveal more (note: the official binaries require a Pentium, which may or may not be a show-stopper, depending on how old the laptop is).  Installing an alternative video adapter may be unfeasible, though given that you have not revealed the laptop model, I cannot tell how much.

Of course, there is still the possibility that this is the fault of bad DOS or Windows driver.  To check that route, you can [follow the steps in Michael Karcher’s answer](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/a/26708/15334).  You can also try interactive boot mode (‘Step-by-step confirmation’ in the <kbd>F8</kbd> boot menu) to pinpoint the driver at fault.  However, if the issues start appearing before any driver loads, or even in ‘Safe mode command prompt only’ mode, there is little hope: it’s almost assuredly a hardware problem.

Answer (score 2):

If booting into safe mode works, it means that your machine is basically working. The issue only occurs when you load additional software that gets skipped when you boot normally. This extra software might be some stuff from autoexec.bat, or it might be a windows graphics driver.

Please try the following troubleshooting steps:

1. Try to boot into "command prompt only" mode (not "command prompt only for safe mode"). If the computer works perfectly in that mode, the issue is *not* in `CONFIG.SYS` or `AUTOEXEC.BAT`.
2. If the issue occurs in "command prompt only" mode, use the confirmation mode to find out what what line of `CONFIG.SYS` or `AUTOEXEC.BAT` causes the issue.
3. If the issue does not occur in "command prompt only" mode, try to re-install the Windows 95 graphics driver, by booting into safe mode and uninstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

Since it can boot and run the startup programs, it would appear to not be a problem with the disk or the RAM.  It seems to be more like the video card, although that's not going to be removable if it's a laptop.  Nonetheless, there is another possibility, that being the printer driver.  Since you can get into safe mode, try removing the printer.  I have rescued machines in the past by doing this, so it's a less than wild guess.